# How to FIND a line of code within an entire folder?

Tags: javascript, drupal

I'm working with drupal and using google's inspect element tool is helping me find the id and class of a button but I cannot find the javascript event handler for this button or anything associated with it in the main BODY php file.

is there a way on a mac or an application that already exists that allows you to search for a string from all HTML, PHP, and JS files?

Comment: what text editor are you using?

Comment: you can track events and put in stops using the inspectors Timeline and source. I don't think there is away to track an element to the function though.

Comment: I use GrepWin for things like this.

Comment: If you're on a mac just use `grep`. Or, if you're feeling _really_ lazy, install Eclipse and hit 'Ctrl+H'

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Resources tab in inspector then press ctrl+f.